# Java regular expression capture group of numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm having a heck of a time getting this regular expression to output the groups I expect:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(point) (.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher("point 0 0 255 0 0");

if (m.find()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.groupCount(); i++) {
        System.out.println("-- " + m.group(i));
    }
}
```

I am hoping to see this output:

```
point 0 0 255 0 0   //  this is group 0
point
0 0 255 0 0
```

Instead, I get group `0` and `1` - nothing from the last group.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In the long run, I'm trying to match `(point|rect|line)` and a variable number of integers.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not printing all the groups. Try `for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)`

Answer (score 1):

Group `0` always refers to the originally matched string - in your example, `point 0 0 255 0 0`.
Therefore, the *numbered capture groups* in your pattern are referred to by a 1-based index - In your example group `1`, group `2`.

This is a common mannerism with other programming languages - JavaScript and Perl also denote the index-zero-match (also referred to as `\0` in "replace" functions) as the whole matched string.

Therefore, to output your expected capture groups, you will need to loop from 0 to 2 or from 1 to 2:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
    //             ^--  changed "<" to "<="
    System.out.println("-- " + m.group(i));
}
```

```
Output:
point 0 0 255 0 0
point
0 0 255 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the MatchResult reference on https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/MatchResult.html and check 'groupCount' section. It is said that group zero denotes the entire pattern by convention and not included in this count.